# Online clustered index rebuild using more log space than expected

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transaction-log, maintenance, clustered-index

I have a table `TableA`

```
ID PK BIGINT
TrxID BIGINT
CardBalance INT
AccountBalance INT
```

`SP_SPACEUSED 'TableA'` output:

```
name    rows       reserved     data         index_size   unused
TableA  904054184  55547120 KB  34661408 KB  19963544 KB  922168 KB
```

So the data size is about 33 GB. There is a *clustered index* on TrxID. There is one nonclustered index, which comes to about 19GB.

My transaction log file size is about 250 GB. `DBCC SQLPERF('logspace')` shows < 1% usage.

When I run:

```
ALTER INDEX CIX_TableA_TrxID ON dbo.TableA REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON)
```

The transaction log hits 100% after about 20 minutes and then continues to grow.

Is there a reliable way to calculate how much log space is required for this operation?

Also this seems like a lot of space to use in the log file, does this sound right?

- This database is in an Availability Group (so using the full recovery model) with 1 other asynchronous replica.
- This is a test database, so there aren't any other transactions running at the same time as the the reindex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting Paul Randal of [SQLSkills](http://SQLSkills.com) he informed me that the reason for the high rates of transaction log usage is that in an `ONLINE` index re/build each row has it's own log record with all the overhead of a log record. An `OFFLINE` rebuild logs full 8kb page images, not row by row.

Related link provided by Paweł Tajs:

[SQL Q&A: The Lore of Logs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh395481.aspx) (also by Paul Randal)